# python into cygwin

Tags: python, cygwin

How to install Python into Cygwin??I have the setup file on my desktop and want to install it into cygwin.

Comment: What's wrong with your [other thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855125/problem-using-sudo-on-cygwin/4855201)?  As I answered there - see [Best way to have full Python install under cygwin/XP](http://serverfault.com/questions/40799/best-way-to-have-full-python-install-under-cygwin-xp)

Comment: That wan not the question from my side

Answer (score 5):

When you go to install Cygwin, it will give you a list of packages to choose from. Under "Interpreters" I believe there is an option to install Python. Anyway, it's in the installer.

Comment: no, it is not installed into my cygwin as it gives me an erro: when I run the command: python setup.pu install - the error is: bash: python: command not found

Comment: @user597293 you have to specify when you install Cygwin that you want Python.

Comment: There is even a group for various Python related packages

Answer (score 2):

To install or update Python in Cygwin, simply run Cygwin's **setup.exe** file.

Once executed, **setup.exe** will display a list of packages, one of which is Python 2.6.xx.